# Button and Menuitem foreground colors overridden by the Textblock style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

This is a style I apply to all the textblocks in the project which is in the App.XAML file.

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    </Style>
```

But this style changes the Foreground colour of all my menu items and the buttons in my project, even if I specify the foreground color to these controls as black. Any solution to this issue?

My XAML for buttons is below:

```
<Button x:Name="BtnEdit" Content="Details" Click="BtnEdit_Click" Margin="10,0,0,0"  />
```

Comment: Can you show the XAML for a typical menu and/or button.

Comment: Specify the foreground of your buttons as `TextElement.Foreground` instead of just `Foreground`. Not including this as an answer because it's a hunch and because it's probably not the best solution anyway.

Comment: Yes its odd as it displays correctly in the designer (buttons black text) - but when app is run button texts are orange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your style from App.xaml App.Resources to MainWindow.xaml Window.Resources.
If you need your style in more than one window or page then move it to a separate resource dictionary xaml file (add -> new -> wfp -> resource dictionary) as per this article:
[resource dictionarys](http://learnwpf.com/post/2006/05/27/How-do-I-separate-out-resources-into-multiple-files-in-WPF.aspx)
Merge the dictionary into the Window.Resources not the Application.Resources as in the example! eg

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
             <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: In that case, I have to repeat the same code in each and every page rite?

Comment: Ive updated my answer to use a separate resource dictionary file - I tested this and it works.  Let me know if its not clear how to set that up.